# Do I need a trigger for a Build Validation pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, yaml

Our dev validation include that each PR triggers a "Build Validation" pipeline. This file contains:

```yaml
trigger:
  - dev
```

The issue is when we're merging to dev, we want another pipeline to trigger, which also contain the trigger `dev`. So when the merge is actually happening, we have 2 pipelines that are executed, which is not optimal.

Here is my thought:
Since the PR validation is actually triggered by the branch policy and not so much the trigger in the file, could I just remove the trigger from the PR Validation pipeline file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: **Yes, you can skip the trigger section**

The `trigger` section does not control whether PR validations run or not, it controls what runs when new commits are pushed to that specific branch (i.e once the pull request is completed)

How you configure your [PR validation triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops) vary depending on your repository type:

## Pull request triggers for Azure Repos

As you say (and as stated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers)) pull request validation builds are configurd using branch policies

> In Azure Repos Git, this functionality is implemented using branch
> policies

## Pull request triggers for GitHub Repos

To trigger pull requets validation on repos hosted in github, add the target branch to the `pr` section (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers) for details)

```yaml
pr:
- dev
```